# How to observe a change on any property in an array or object?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want to do something like this

```
    Polymer('bc-datalist', {
        listitems: [
            {name: 'item1'},
            {name: 'item2'}
        ],
        observe: {
            'listitems': 'change'
        },
        change: function () {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

This doesn't work, so my work around is to do something like this:

```
    Polymer('bc-datalist', {
        listitems: {
            1:{name: 'item1'},
            2:{name: 'item2'}
        },
        observe: {
            'listitems.1.name': 'change',
            'listitems.2.name': 'change'
        },
        change: function () {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

Is there a way of registering a callback when a object/array item has changed?

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it would appear that there's a typo in your first example. Where you mean to reference `listitems` as the object to observe, you reference `listitem` instead. Changing this to `listitems` would make the case for normal top-level properties work:

```
<polymer-element name="test-el">
  <template>
    <button on-click="{{clickHandler}}">Click me</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('test-el', {
        listitems: [
            {name: 'item1'},
            {name: 'item2'}
        ],
        observe: {
            'listitems': 'change'
        },
        change: function () {
            // do something
            alert('listitems changed!');
        },
        clickHandler: function(){
          this.listitems.push({ name: 'item3'});
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Onto your question: Polymer does not call the `propertyNameChanged` callback for properties included in an observe block to the best of my knowledge. This means you will need to specify the exact nested object path (a.b.c) for what you are trying to observe or manually setup the relevant type of Path/Compound observer manually: https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js

Comment: Polymer's [observe-js](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js) library has support for path observation into an object and Polymer has 1st class support for this. See the [2nd example in the docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeblock))

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Thanks for the answer, this clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

Polymer's [observe-js](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js) library has support for path observation into an object as well as [array observation](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js#arrayobserver). The former, can be setup similar to what you have (see [2nd example in the docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeblock)).

```
Polymer('x-element', {
  observe: {
    'a.b.c': 'validateSubPath'
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.a = {
      b: {
        c: 'exists'
      }
    };
  },
  validateSubPath: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    var value = Path.get('a.b.c').getValueFrom(this);
    // oldValue == undefined
    // newValue == value == this.a.b.c === 'exists'
  }
});
```

I'm checking on ArrayObserver support. Will update this post when I know more.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of objects and would like to observe changes made to any of those objects' properties, you can try a custom element, [`<observe-array-items>`](https://github.com/jeffposnick/observe-array-items). It simplifies the process of creating individual [`PathObserver`](https://github.com/polymer/observe-js#pathobserver)s for all of the objects in the array, and maintains them as items are added/removed from the list.

In your example, you could do something like

```
<polymer-element name="test-el">
  <template>
    <observe-array-items array="{{listitems}}"
                         path="name"
                         on-array-item-changed="{{handleNameChanged}}">
    </observe-array-items>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        listitems: [
            {name: 'item1'},
            {name: 'item2'}
        ],
        handleNameChanged: function (e) {
          // This will be called whenever the 'name' property
          //   of an existing object in listitems changes.
          // e.detail.oldValue and e.detail.newValue will
          //   contain the old and current values
          // e.detail.index will correspond to the index of the object in the array.
        },
        listitemsChanged: function() {
          // This will be called whenever an object is added or removed from listitems
        }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```